# onTokenRefresh is not fired in rnfirebase Library for React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

```
 this.onTokenRefreshListener = firebase
.messaging()
.onTokenRefresh(fcmToken => {
  // Process your token as required
  console.log("fcmToken onTokenRefresh", fcmToken);
  console.log("fcmToken onTokenRefresh client", client);
  // await AsyncStorage.setItem("fcmToken", fcmToken);
  sendDeviceTokenToServerOnTokenRefresh(client, fcmToken);
  console.log("fcmToken onTokenRefresh after", fcmToken);
});
```

This has been used in componentDidMount. 
OnTokenRefresh is not fired, I have tested many time by generating new token by deleting the app cache. new token is available if i use firebase.messaging().getToken(). But onTokenRefresh seems to be inactive.
I could be a possibility the token has been generated much before the call of componentDidMount.
Let me know if anyone have faced the same issue.

Comment: which version of firebase react native are you using?

Comment: @GauravRoy "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.4" .